# Parsing different data types with Python

Tags: python, file, parsing, graph

I want to parse the following line:

**#3 = IFCPERSONANDORGANIZATION(#4, #5, $);**

and want to extract the numbers: 3, 4 , 5 to integer values and 'IFCPERSONANDORGANIZATION' as string value, in order to save these attributes in a graph with networkx.

This my code:

```
data = []
with open('test.ifc') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('#'):
            words = line.rstrip().split('#')
            print(words)
            node = int(words[0])
            data.append(node)
```

Error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

How can I use regex, if the line structure is different every time? Like this:

```
#3 = IFCPERSONANDORGANIZATION(#4, #5, $);
#2 = IFCOWNERHISTORY(#3, #6, $, .NOTDEFINED., $, $, $, 1348486883);
#4 = IFCPERSON($, 'Bonsma', 'Peter', $, $, $, $, $);
#5 = IFCORGANIZATION($, 'RDF', 'RDF Ltd.', $, $);
#6 = IFCAPPLICATION(#5, '0.10', 'Test Application', 'TA 1001');****
```

Comment: You `print(words)`, why did you think the first element could be made an integer?

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex:

```
import re
line = '#3 = IFCPERSONANDORGANIZATION(#4, #5, $);'
node, name, a, b = re.search(r'(\d+) = (\w+)\(#(\d+), #(\d+), \$\)', line).groups()
node, a, b = map(int, [node, a, b])
print(node, name, a, b)
```

prints

```
3 IFCPERSONANDORGANIZATION 4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

May be a late comment but I come up with your question and given answers when I am making a similar search. [@user3926906](http://@user3926906) an IFC file structure is generally changing for each different file. When you are using `re.search()` did you experience any challenge to split the `#` of entities? I am asking because some of the entities does not `#` for referring other entities. Thanks